# Why can't I find my factor names when I extract residuals?

Tags: r, regression

I'm working with some election data trying to separate it by "state" and "election."
I ran a regression with fixed effects for state and year (as you'll see below), got my summary data, and have been trying to use the resid() function to extract the residuals.

```
m5 <- lm(demVote ~ state*year, data=presidentialElections)

plot(resid(m5) ~ fitted(m5))
resid.m5 <- resid(m5)
```

I think it all worked above just perfectly. However, here's where I'm lost - if I do summary(resid.m5) (where I put the extracted residuals, or so I thought), I can't seem to find my factor names anymore. If I want to see my residuals per state or per year (or an average of them by state/year, for example) then how do I access that with the resid() function? Thanks!

Comment: The order of residuals should match the order of `state` and `year` in  `presidentialElections`, so depending on what you want to do with the grouped resids, you could do something like: `plot(resid.m5 ~ presidentialElections$state)`, or `aggregate(resid.m5, list(presidentialElections$state, presidentialElections$year), mean)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as was said in the comments before, you have to realize that the residuals that are being returned are in the same order as your observations in the data set.

Here is an example using the iris data set that comes with every R installation (and a probably quite nonsensical regression):

```
data(iris)
m5 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species*Sepal.Width, data=iris)
resid.m5 <- resid(m5)

dta.complete <- data.frame(iris, r.m5=resid.m5)
```

Here, the residuals are combined with the original data. It is perhaps a little unorthodox, but why not keep things together. Now you can use all the classical subsetting as much as you like. For instance:

```
with(dta.complete, by(r.m5, Species, mean))
```

Good luck!

Comment: A bit of care is needed if there are missing data; as the length of the residual vector will not equal the number of rows of original data, order has chnaged- could perhaps use m5$model instead of original df iris